# How can I delete my filtered rows after copying to new sheet?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am requiring a script that deletes my filtered rows after copying them to a new sheet.

This is the code I have to filter and copy to a new sheet:

```
function archiveData() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const values = ss.getRange('Template!A3:S')
    .getValues()
    .filter(row => row[18]); // column S
    const targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Archive');
  appendRows_(targetSheet, values, 1);
}
```

It makes use of [appendRows_()](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/159417/how-to-append-a-cell-value-to-a-certain-column-d2d/159426#159426)
I have tried the following code but no avail:

```
const ws = ss.getSheetByName("Template");  
const colSData = ws.getRange('S3:S').getValues();  

for(let i =colSData.length-1;i>=0;i--){   
   if(colSData[i][0] == true){     
   //console.log(colSData);     
   ws.deleteRows(i+1);   
   } 
 }
```

Comment: try with ```for(let i =colSData.length-3;i>=0;i--) ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your script, as a simple modification, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
ws.deleteRows(i+1);
```

#### To:

```
ws.deleteRows(i + 3);
```

- In your script, the values are retrieved with `const colSData = ws.getRange('S3:S').getValues();`. By this, I thought that `ws.deleteRows(i+1);` might be required to be modified to `ws.deleteRows(i + 3);`.
- By the way, in your script, when `const colSData = ws.getRange('S3:S').getValues();` is modified to `const colSData = ws.getRange('S3:S' + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();`, the process cost might be a bit reduced.